# d3.js: Get data out of synchronous brush selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my project i got multiple dynamically (in this example three) rendered charts.

The synchronous selection over multiple charts when you make a selection in one chart is one of the key features.

Is there a possibility to get the selected data out of all 3 selections after you made a selection in one chart? In best case it should `console.log()` three different arrays with the different selected data points.

I added an [working example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1mv3ec9/).

I already tried to `console.log(event)` in the `.on("end", ...)` of the `selectBrush` but it only gives me back the selection event of one chart.

Here is the whole `selectBrush` code:

```
 var selectBrush = d3
  .brushX()
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height],
  ])
  .on("brush", selectBrushed)
  .on("end", function (event) {
    if (event.selection == null) {
      resetSelection();
    }
  });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

1. Return the selected domain of the x scale after each brush event. Cache the data globally for all 3 charts and filter each for the selected domain range and output it.
2. Extract the data from the __data__ property of the line element after each brush event and return it. Just console log the d3 selection for the line element and look into the _groups property tree. You will find the __data__ property.

Comment: The 2. option sounds good. How would you do it exactly. I dont realy know where i exacti I have to put the return for the property?

Comment: No. what I want to archive now has nothing to do with the minimap. As you can seein the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1mv3ec9/) If you do a selection In one of the charts (out of the minimap) you get the same selection on the other charts too (in this case on the other two charts). Now i want the data of all the 3 selections from the selected charts. Is it allowed to write in german in SO maybe i can explain the problem better to you in german?